# Retrieving records in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to ember js. I have a form & when a user hit submit i want to check whether the username & password that user have entered, is already in my model/database.I tried following,But it didn't work. Please help me with this...

Template

```
<h2>Welcome to my blog</h2>

 <form {{action 'exist' on="submit"}}>

        <dl>
        <dt>User Name:<br> {{textarea value=uName cols="20" rows="1"}}</dt>
        <dt>Password:<br> {{textarea value=passw cols="20" rows="1"}}</dt>
        </dl>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
 </form>
```

Model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

    FirstName: DS.attr('string'),
    UserName: DS.attr('string'),
    Password: DS.attr('string'),
    PermissionList: DS.attr('array')

});
```

Route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user');
    }
});
```

Controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        ght: function () {
            var uName = this.get('uName');
            var passw = this.get('passw');

            if (this.store.find('user', {
                userName: this.get('uName')
            })) {
                alert('Already exist');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

// This alert is shown for every input.Even they are not in the model

Answer (score 0):

as `store.find()` always returns a promise which is an object, `if` condition always evaluates to true. What you should probably do is you've to wait for the promise to resolve and do the check like

```
// ...
var uName = this.get('uName');
this.store.find('user', {
    userName: uName
}).then(function(user) {
    if(user) {
        alert('Already exist');
    } else {

    }
});
// ...
```

Comment: Still having the same problem

Comment: What is your problem? The code he provided works the way it's supposed to. You need to resolve promise first to check its uniquness against your database.

Comment: This code should be working. Can you add more precision? What is  the value of user in the resolved promise function?

Answer (score 0):

This form looks like a login form. If my assumption is right you don't show this form if user is already logged in ( in this case the session will have user info). In case if user is not logged in you will have to show form. I don't think you will need to search user in store. Just send/save user to server and do the user find logic on server side and send response accordingly. On ember side you can show exist result by handling .then of promises.

If your use case is different you can use query(for multiple records). and queryRecord for single record

[Query](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/finding-records/)

Copy pasted from documents

```
// GET to /persons?filter[name]=Peter
this.store.query('person', { filter: { name: 'Peter' } }).then(function(peters) {
  // Do something with `peters`
});


// GET to /persons?filter[email]=tomster@example.com
this.store.queryRecord('person', { filter: { email: 'tomster@example.com' } }).then(function(tomster) {
  // do something with `tomster`
});
```

//on mobile will add code if this doesn't help